# Sequential program that accesses the whole of the array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multithreading, sequential

I'm working on threads, however before I use threads I am to write 2 programs.

1. Set up an array and write a sequential program that accesses the whole of the array and performs some simple task on the contents.
2. Modify the program so that it is still sequential but accesses the array by a series of calls to a function. Each call to that function will process a number of rows of the array as defined by a parameter passed to the function.

I'm having problems understanding the questions, it seems so simple but yet I can't seem to get my head around it. I am to write the programs based on the above two questions before I start creating a program that will allow the processing to be carried out in one or more threads. Each thread should access a different set of rows of the array.

For the first question, the code I have written so far is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array [20][20];
    int i, j;

    /* output each array element's value */
   for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
      {
         printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, array[i][j] );
      }
   }
   system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know if the above program is a sequential program? I have run the program and it access the whole array and  perform one tasks which is to print out all data in the arrays.

I researched on on-line what it means by sequential program  and I found it means the following statement: perform task a before task b but not at the same time. Is this right?

For the second part I have done the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int array[20][20]);

int main()
{
    int array [20][20];
    int i, j;

    print_array(array);

   system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

// Output data in an array
void print_array(int array)
{
    int  i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
      {
         printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, array[i][j] );
      }
   }
}
```

Am I going in the right direction? As I also got to write a version of the program that will allow the processing to be carried out in one or more threads.

EDIT: I am to use 2D arrays, sorry it wasn't clear above

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going in the right direction, but you're not far off. What the instructions are asking for are some of the preliminary steps needed to take the work of processing an array sequentially and make it run in parallel. When writing a parallel program, it is often useful to start with a working sequential program and slowly transform it into a parallel program. Following the instructions is a way to do this.

Let's consider the parts of the question separately:

- Set up an array and write a sequential program that accesses the whole of the array and performs some simple task on the contents.

The simple task that you chose for your array is to print the contents, but this isn't a suitable task, because it has no functional result. A more suitable task would be the sum the elements in the array. Other tasks might be count the elements that meet some condition, or to multiple each element by two.

So, first try to modify your initial program to sum the elements instead of printing them.

(In your code you are using a two-dimensional array. I would suggest using a 1-dimensional array for simplicity.)

- Modify the program so that it is still sequential but accesses the array by a series of calls to a function. Each call to that function will process a number of rows of the array as defined by a parameter passed to the function.

In this part what you are trying to do is break up the functionality into small pieces of work. (Eventually you will send these units of work to threads for processing, but you are just doing the preliminary steps now.) If we did a sum in part 1, then here you might write a function which is `int sumKitems(int *array, int startIndex, int numItems)`. The main program would then call this on each set of (say) 10 items in the array, and combine the full results by summing the results from each `sumKitems` call.

So, if there are 100 items in the array, you could make 10 calls to `sumKitems(...)`, telling the function to process 0...9, 10...19, ..., 90...99. This would be in place of doing the sum on all 100 items individually.

--

To summarize, part one would be a simple for loop, not too differently from what you've written, just with some computation being performed.

The second part should do exactly the same computation and return exactly the same result, just using another function call which handles `k` items at time. (If you pass the number of items to handle at a time as a parameter you will be able to balance the cost of communication vs work being done when moving to a threaded implementation.)

In the end, you will probably be asked to replace the call to `sumKitems(...)` with a queue that sends work to the threads to do independently.

Comment: In addition, to achieve the same result in both setups, I suggest to initialize the array to known values.

Comment: Definitely -- you need to be able to validate that things still work every step of the way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you are not creating separate threads in any way then you are in fact writing a sequential program. There is no part of your code where you jump into a new thread to do some operation while the main thread does something else.

Summary: your code runs on a single thread - it is sequential

You must pass the array not as an integer but as a double pointer -> `int array[][]` or `int** array`

Answer (score 0):

To perform operations on the array sequentially would be to start at the first place in the array and increment through the array performing operations as you go

```
array[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
  iterate through array with some action such as adding +5
  array [10] = {5,6....}
```

To make this multi-threaded you need to have different threads operate on different segments of the array such as places 0-4,5-9 and perform the action so it can be done in less time. If you're doing it this way you will not need to worry about mutexes.

So Thread one increments through array[10] {0,1,2,3}

Thread two increments through array[10] {4,5,6,7}

Each increment one place at a time and both threads run concurrently